# Skiasharp for map overlays

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I currently am using win2d and bing maps to draw polygon overlays on a bing map in a uwp project. I would like to use skiasharp to draw the overlays using a surface pen. 
Is it possible to use skiasharp for this purpose?

Comment: Hi man! Would u mind to share your approach how to du draw polygons and win2d please?

Answer (score 0):

It could work. You can export SkiaSharp drawing as a transparent PNG, so if you can display PNG over your map, then you can use it.

Comment: I  need to trace an area of the map, so I would need the map below the skiasharp canvas

Comment: You don't need to use SkiaSharp canvas, you can just paint into memory and export to transparent PNG and display PNG over your map.

Comment: I want to use skiasharp. The project is to map golf courses and use the skiasharp to display the mapped course in a xamarin form's apo